# Creating border on the div element and bind event

Tags: javascript, css

I have this div:

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:green"></div>
```

I need to create border from right side of the `div` and to bind to the border mouse down event.

How can I implement it?

Here what I tried

But the problem is that `StartResizing` function is fired when mouse down occurs not only on the rightBorder but also on the PropertyArea.

How can I prevent `StartResizing` in propertyArea div?

```js
function StartResizingPropertiesWindow(e) {
  console.log(e.clientX,e.clientY,e.target);
}
```

```html
<div id="rightBorder" style="border-right:5px solid black;width:100px; height:100px" onmousedown="return StartResizingPropertiesWindow(event)">
  <div id="PropertyArea" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: With more than 2k rep you should know to create a [mcve]

Comment: you're probably going to want to look into css classes. You try looking up `border-right` and `:active`

Comment: @tylermackenzie, is it so easy to implement?I need to fire function only when I click on the border

Comment: oh, I thought you meant you wanted the border to change when you click the div. but you want to call a javascript function when just the border is clicked and not the rest of the element?

Comment: @tylermackenzie yes. I updated question please see it

Comment: Ah, Now you're starting to have a real question... I'll try posting an answer for you

Comment: `<div id="PropertyArea" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:green" onmousedown="return false;"></div>` ??

Comment: See the snippet I wrote. Now look at the event.target and the cordinates

Answer (score 0):

I think if you add `pointer-events: none;` to the "propertyArea" div. it might give you the desired effect.

It should change how clicks and mouse events are handled on that div. whether they can pass through or not, etc.

Comment: Thanks for help but it didn't change anything when I put it in PropertyArea